# Not returning content in python function

Tags: python

I trying to write a code to monitor website dayly, but i got sutck in a return of a function. When i execute this script, i got the error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-071caa90924c> in <module>
     62 salva_arquivo(url)
     63 checa_existe_anterior(url)
---> 64 pesquisa_diferenca(conteudo_old,conteudo_new)
     65 
     66 

NameError: name 'conteudo_old' is not defined
```

But when i try to print(conteudo_old) or (conteudo_new) inside the function, they do exist and has content. However, if i execute all the script calling the functions in the end, i got this error. Does anyone know? tks

```
import requests, urllib3, httplib2
import os
from datetime import *
import difflib
import string
import csv

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.example.com'

def salva_arquivo(url):
    ## Primeiro  - Cria o nome
    nomesite = "".join([i.replace(i, "") if i not in string.ascii_letters else i for i in url])
    dataHoje = date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    nomesite_new = f"{nomesite}_{dataHoje}.html"
    response = requests.get(url)
    conteudo_new = str(response.content)
    ## Segundo - Cria e Grava o Arquivo
    with open (nomesite_new, encoding='utf-8', mode = 'w+') as nomesite_new:
         nomesite_new.write(conteudo_new)
    return conteudo_new


def checa_existe_anterior (url):
    ## Cria o nome do site de ontem
    dataOntem = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    nomesite = "".join([i.replace(i, "") if i not in string.ascii_letters else i for i in url])
    nomesite_old = f"{nomesite}_{dataOntem}.html"
    ## Procura se existe o arquivo no diretório    
    for files in os.listdir(): 
        if str(files) == str(nomesite_old):
            with open (nomesite_old, mode = 'r') as nomesite:
                conteudo_old = nomesite.read()
        elif conteudo_old == None:
            print('nao encontrei')
    return conteudo_old



def pesquisa_diferenca(conteudo_old, conteudo_new):
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, conteudo_old, conteudo_new)
    for block in s.get_matching_blocks():
        print(block)
        pass

salva_arquivo(url)
checa_existe_anterior(url)
pesquisa_diferenca(conteudo_old,conteudo_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return values of the functions to the variables so you can use them to call the next function.

```
conteudo_new = salva_arquivo(url)
conteudo_old = checa_existe_anterior(url)
pesquisa_diferenca(conteudo_old,conteudo_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `checa_existe_anterior` function defines a [*local* variable](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables) named `conteudo_old` but that name expires when the function ends -- that is, when the indentation level goes back to zero.

You could make another instance of the `conteudo_old` variable at the module/global scope, like this:

```
conteudo_old = checa_existe_anterior(...)
```

And then when you passed it into your `pesquisa_diferenca` function it would exist.

Beware, however: there appears to be a bug in your `checa_existe_anterior` function.

You have:

```
for files in os.listdir(): 
    if str(files) == str(nomesite_old):
        with open (nomesite_old, mode = 'r') as nomesite:
            conteudo_old = nomesite.read()
    elif conteudo_old == None:
        print('nao encontrei')
return conteudo_old
```

First, it is possible for a `for` loop to run zero times. In this case, `os.listdir` is documented to *not* return the `.` and `..` members, so an otherwise-empty directory will cause this. When that happens, `conteudo_old` has never been set since the only place it gets set is inside the loop, which never runs. You would have an error exactly like the one you describe.

Second, consider what happens if the *first* file encountered matches the `if` condition: this would attempt to open the file. But if the file cannot be opened (perhaps because of permission problems), the `with` statement will silently exit and `conteudo_old` is never initialized. Then you try to return it, which would cause an error exactly like the one you describe.

Finally, please be aware that `== None` is considered bad practice according to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51) and should be replaced by `is None`.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me a lot.